# jquery ui accordion need different actions for link vs. icon

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to use JQuery UI Accordion for a multi-level menu, like a Superfish menu, but with vertial accordion presentation instead.  For example:

- Home
- Products
- - product category 1
- - product category 2

The 'main menu' level items are linked to the corresponding page, so in this example, 'products' is linked to the 'products' page.  In the accordion menu, if you click the '+' to open the 'products' menu, the 'products' link is activated and you are taken to the 'products' page.

This seems wrong to me.  The '+' should open the menu, but not activate the link.  A user should have to click on the 'products' link itself to activate it.

Is there a configuration option or jQuery function I can use to trigger different actions for the link and the '+'?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of event bubbling. 
I don't use jQuery UI but I give you an example:

```
<a href="whatyouwant.html"><span class="himg"></span></a>
<script>
$('a').click(function(){menuclick(this)})
$('span').click(function(){menuclick($(this).parent());return false})
</script>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/keszlercsaba/qqwPS/ 
Give a try.